# For Objective-C what is the most efficient way to implement value pair arrays?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

Say I have an Item and each of the item has a date of purchase attached to it.

What is the best way to store the pair so I can put it into NSUserdefaults and retrive it later?

Thanks

Comment: Core Data is the best solution, it's extendable, easily integrated, and just rocks!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Respectfully have to disagree that it is the best solution for OP's needs. If all you need to do is persist a short list then Core Data is overkill, unless there are other requirements yet to be revealed.

Comment: Storing anything other than configuration data in NSUserDefaults is generally a bad idea. Serialise the data to disk and reload it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You can use the NSString form of the item as a key and the date of purchase as an NSDate value when persisted to NSUserDefaults.

But NSUserDefaults was intended more for configurations than as a general purpose DB.  Use Core Data as Richard J. Ross III mentioned or SQLite.  You never know, your data schema may change and become more involved in which case a DB (or at least a file) is in order.

Comment: An additional complexity question. what if i need an item:date:bool(yes/no) triplet? The amount of data will not be big.

Comment: Well, NSUserDefaults is really intended for "key + value" style storage of small amounts of data.  Once the data gets beyond that you might consider just using files and NSCoding as @CarlVaezey mentioned below.You'd encode the entire item in the file (including the date and bool).  The filename could be some unique ID like a GUID or item code like ISBN.  Then it's just a matter of reading/writing files.  If you need search capabilities though you'll want to go with an SQL approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

If `Item` is a fairly simple class without a lot of relationships than need to be modeled, you could implement `NSCoding` on it, store each in a dictionary along with its purchase date, put all the dictionaries in an array, then use `NSKeyedArchiver` to turn the array to `NSData` and write that to a file on disk. You could even skip implementing NSCoding and store a unique string or number identifying the item in the dictionary instead of the item, assuming you don't have so many items to necessitate a database.

If the size of your dataset or complexity of your objects is moderate to high I'd agree with Richard J. Ross III and Jason Fuerstenberg and recommend core data or SQLite.